# Serializability and the Lost Update Problem

Tags: concurrency, database-theory

[Serializability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability) is the strongest consistency level with regard to the execution of two concurrent transactions T1 and T2. That is, if T1 and T2 independently change the application between consistent states, and a concurrent execution of T1 and T2 is equivalent to a serial execution of T1 and T2, then that concurrent execution results in a consistent state, after committing both transactions.

For example, the following concurrent execution (time advances to the right)

```
T1: w(a=1)         w(c=4)
T2:     w(a=2)w(b=3)
```

where `W(x=v)` sets (i.e., writes) `x` to the value `v`, is equivalent to the serial execution `T1;T2`, thus it is serializable and both transactions are committed.

However, it is clear that T2's write of `a` causes T1's write of `a` to be lost, i.e., we have a lost update despite serializability.

That is, **serializability ensures consistent states in face of concurrency, though it does not prevent lost updates**, which may have serious consequences (for example, imagine that T1 writes the correct delivery address of a VIP customer, and T2 writes the wrong address, T1 and T2 are run concurrently by different operators, who do not notice the mistake).

Is my statement correct about serializability and lost updates?

If it is correct then the table in "Isolation levels, read phenomena, and locks" in this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) can only be wrong with regard to serializability and lost updates.

If so, what other stronger consistency level ensures that there are no lost updates?

Thanks

Comment: I highly recommend Bailis et al's [Highly Available Transactions: Virtues and Limitations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0309) for a concise but rather comprehensive overview of database isolation and data consistency models. Table 3 and Figure 2 provide an even more concise overview and clearly indicate that serializability and even weaker isolation levels prevent lost updates, so your statement is not correct.

Comment: @DerekElkins I have read that article just before asking this question! The point is that the "Lost Update" case in the article (sec 5.2.1) is a different one, in which case there is no serializable execution. Now my point here is a different "Lost Update" situation, one in that the concurrent execution is serializable, though one of the updates is silently lost.

Comment: @DerekElkins My point is that serializability does not prevent all situations of "lost update", like in the case of *blind writes*.

Comment: If you want to use a different meaning of "lost update", I would recommend either making it clear that you are doing that or, preferably, finding a different way of saying that rather than reusing a technical term. I don't see why you describe the situation in your question as a "lost update". How is the scenario you describe any different from running all of T1 before all of T2? The end result is still a wrong address. Do we "lose an update" *any* time two transactions write to the same variable?

Comment: @DerekElkins ok, now we are reaching to something that I was suspicious of. Unfortunately, I saw nowhere a clear statement of what is meant by "lost update" in the database world, and how does it distinguishes from "lost update" in real-world. If you have such reference, please tell me. So now it is a matter of what programmers want their applications to behave, that is, if they want to avoid inadvertent real-world "lost updates", in which case serializability is not enough, or does not care at all. Personally, I tend to the former.

Comment: Can you answer the question I asked about how the situation would be any different if all the writes of T1 actually did occur before T2? As far as I can tell, you view this situation as acceptable (i.e. no update is "lost"), but the end result is exactly the same: `a=2` at the end, i.e. the wrong address is there.

Comment: @DerekElkins Yes sure. So, the case of `T1;T2` is no different, obviously, and I consider also not acceptable: it is application bad design to let anyone overwrite someone's update silently, despite a concurrent or serial execution. My point is that I read in the Internet (e.g., Wikipedia) that "serializability prevents lost updates", but it only does so for some cases of lost updates, most notably that of Berenson et al. (https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=223785), and probably other cases, but not all cases, as I demonstrated. And I think programmers must be aware of that.

Comment: What you just said means that you think no variable should be updated by two transactions *ever*. That is, the first transaction that writes to a variable is the only transaction that can *ever* write to that variable otherwise we would "lose" the first transaction's update. I doubt you intend that, so let me turn this around: when *is* a write to a variable *not* a "lost" update when another transaction, possibly started long after the first transaction has completed, also writes to that variable? In what situations can two transactions write to a variable without causing a "lost update"?

Comment: @DerekElkins That's a really interesting question. I would say that data that is not read should not be allowed to be overwritten, or one must be sure to use locks, so that way no updates can be silently ignored. Consequently, transactions `T1` and `T2`, in my example, are badly designed! This means that one must introduce *awareness* in our applications, either through reads or locks. I did not meant that "no variable should be updated by two transactions ever": It can simply be done, but there must be some awareness mechanism buit in, like a read or a lock, to avoid losing updates silently.

Comment: I don't see how your proposed feature actually helps. In the scenario you described, why does the web form,say, that the user used to enter the (wrong) email address need to perform a read of a field that it is going to overwrite? As far as I can tell, in your proposed approach, if this was made as a blind write, it would be aborted. Then what does the user do? Run some read-only transaction so the T1 update wouldn't be "lost", then rerun their blind write transaction? What if someone else had read `a` before T2 was attempted, would that allow T2 to (silently) succeed?

Comment: @DerekElkins An attempt of transaction to write a data item that was written in concurrency by a committed transaction must result in an abort or restart of the first. In the example, if `T1` held a lock on `a` until committed, that would force `T2` to wait for lock release, or to abort immediately. In both cases,`T2` should be designed to read `a` so that the user would see that `a` was changed in the meantime. See Optimistic Offline Lock (https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html), another possible solution which uses versioned data items to help with concurrency.

Comment: I'm not talking about overlapping transactions (not that it matters). I'm talking about a situation where T1 runs to completion, then T2 starts. Earlier you said that you would also treat this as a "lost" update situation.

Comment: @DerekElkins Well, what is really important, in my point of view, is to not overwrite someone's update without noticing it. Just that. How this is guaranteed is just an implementation detail. For example, version control databases, like Git and Subversion, support it. But YMMV.

Comment: What constitutes "noticing"? That was the crux of my previous question. At any rate, those systems require *human* intervention when conflicts are detected. What the heck is the database supposed to do? There may be no human that initiated the transaction, and even if there was there may be no "merge" user interface. If I check some timestamp field to ensure my change is the latest, how is the database going to know that that has any relevance to some other field? Git isn't an OLTP database. Facebook supports friending. That doesn't make it clear what adding friending to a database means.

Comment: @DerekElkins By "noticing" it can be the transaction support mechanism to detect the above write-write conflict somehow (e.g., the write-sets intersect between `T1` and `T2`), and then abort and restart one of the transactions. Applications can also be designed to have a "merge" user interface if necessary, or opt to lock data while the user is editing it (see Martin Fowler's Pessimistic Offline Lock). Irrespective of the solution, my view is that inadvertently losing someone's edit is probably not acceptable for some applications, of which version control is one important example.

Comment: @DerekElkins And I am not aware of the Facebook's solution you refer (link?).

Comment: @DerekElkins One more comment. The case I brought here is similar to that in [write-write conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write%E2%80%93write_conflict) with the difference that mine is serializable. So in my case `T2` is "overwriting uncommitted data" which is "a computational anomaly associated with interleaved execution of transactions", corresponding to a "lost update". According to that Wikipedia page it seems that "Strict 2PL overcomes this inconsistency by locking".

Comment: @DerekElkins You may like to read the answer I just post. I think it clarifies well the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> **serializability ensures consistent states in face of concurrency, though it does not prevent lost updates**

This is not true, since by definition the *lost update* is the phenomenon arising in presence of [Write-write conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write%E2%80%93write_conflict), that is when a transaction B overwrites a value written by a transaction A *before the commit of A*. This operation *can* lead to a state which cannot arise from any serial execution of A and B.

Consider for instance, in your example, the case in which the transaction T2 is executed one hour after the transaction T1: this could happen in real life, the execution of the two transactions is serial, that is there is no interference between the two transactions, however the update is wrong since someone wrote a bad address. But this means bad data, not data base inconsistency in itself (in other words, you have a database inconsistent with the reality, but this has nothing to do with concurrency and transaction management, that are properties related to the execution of concurrent operations over the database).

Comment: The link you give is a case of lost update that is detected as no concurrent execution is equivalent to a serial order of `Ta` and `Tb`. The case you give after "that this [sic] when a transaction B ..." is one of *blind writes* and is serializable (it is equivalent to `Ta;Tb`). And you did not understand my point: serializability ensures consistent application/database states, always, but it does not prevent situations when updates are silently ignored. However, there are "databases" that really prevent the kind of lost update I gave in my example, like version control tools.

Comment: Version control has nothing to do with databases: the serializability theory is an old and well established theory that talks not about the consistency of the database with respect to the real world. If you don't want to lose any update, you can use version based-databases or historical databases, where no data is modified or deleted, but only added. Or you imagine that the application or the database know when an update is a correct update or is wrong? Under which bases?

Comment: My example is a case of write-write conflict on variable `a`, as per the link you gave as it is "overwriting uncommitted data", though it is still serializable.

Comment: The example given in the wikipedia page is not serializable, while your is, and if fact it is not prohibited by the theory (but note that real-life serializers of DBMS working with the Two-Strict Phase Protocol do not allow the concurrent execution of the two transactions, since T1 blocks `a` until it commits.)

Comment: Right, using write locks (I believe that's what you are mentioning regarding real-life serializers) prevents the "lost update" I gave in the example. The trouble here is the definition of what is a Lost Update, which if it is that given by Berenson et al. (see https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=223785) is limited, as it does not consider lost update cases that version control databases, like Git, do capture.

Comment: I would say that serializability captures lost updates as defined by Berenson et al., and probably others, but not all cases of lost updates, as I have shown. I would say that Berenson et al. give a strict definition of what is a lost update, whereas a safer definition is to consider all updates that can be silently lost due to concurrency issues. It is the safer definition that version control databases support. (Yes, tools like Git are databases, though not traditional SQL ones).

Comment: In the paper that you linked, it is said: “(Lost Update): The lost update anomaly occurs when transaction T1 reads a data item and then T2 updates the data item (possibly based on a previous read), then T1 (based on its earlier read value) updates the data item and commits.”. So, this is not the case of “Lost Update” of your example. Finally, note that the concurrency theory has been defined for SQL transaction-based databases, and *cannot be applied* to any other context, like Git repositories. Otherwise we could use the terms at our will, always.

Comment: Unfortunately (or not), there is concurrency too with other kinds of databases, in which "lost updates" are like the ones I gave in my example. Perhaps it was my fault to mix the two worlds ... perhaps, we need a Unified Theory of Concurrency. ;-)

Comment: That is a interesting point of view! I think it could be explored somehow.

Comment: Not much time to explore that, but I agree with you.

Comment: You may like to read the answer I just post. I think it clarifies well the question.

Comment: The example you give regarding non-serializability is the case F3 in the [Schedule Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schedule_(computer_science)#Avoids_cascading_aborts_/_rollbacks_(ACA)). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The case above of transactions T1 and T2 is one of Dirty Writes, not of Lost Update. Let me explain what I have been learning regarding this phenomena (see paper [A Critique of ANSI SQL Isolation Levels](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=69541) by Berenson et al, 1995).

I confounded these two phenomena because they are very similar when comparing the execution schedules of two concurrent transactions provoking each phenomenon. The trap is that both phenomena involve writes to the same data item in two  transactions.

A Dirty Write happens when one transaction writes a data item, but does not finish (i.e., commit or abort) before another transaction writes the same data item in concurrency. Dirty writes are precluded in all databases, typically by putting a write (exclusive) lock as the data item is written, thus blocking other transactions trying to write the same data item until the one holding the lock finishes. This means that the schedule in this question (above) cannot happen in reality because T2 would block waiting for T1 to finish.

In contrast, a Lost Update happens when one transaction writes a data item and commits, then a second (concurrent) transaction writes the same data item based on a value of the data item read before the write of the first transaction, therefore if the second transaction commits the update of the first is lost. Lost Updates are avoided at isolation levels stronger than READ COMMITTED.